# Postgres: Searching over jsonb array field is slow

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

We are changing DB(PostgreSQL 10.11) structure for one of our projects. And one of the changes is moving field of type uuid[] (called “areasoflawid”) into the jsonb field (called “data”).

So, we have a table which look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.documents
(
  id serial,
  areasoflawid uuid[], --the field to be moved into the ‘data’
  data jsonb,
  ….
)
```

We are not changing the values of the array or its structure. 
i.e. documents.data->'metadata'->'areaoflawids' contains the same items as documents.areasoflawid)
After data migration, the JSON stored in the “data” field has following structure:

```
{
   ...
   "metadata": {
      ...
      "areaoflawids": [
         "e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b",
         "b3af9163-d910-4d19-8f40-0602b75c25b0",
         "50dc7fd8-ebdf-4cd2-bcab-b8d755fe96e8",
         "8955c062-363f-4a1a-ac3c-d1c2ffe96c9b",
         "bdb79f9f-4539-45f5-ac82-92baaf915f6c"
      ],
      ....
   },
   ...
}
```

So, after migrating data we started benchmarking jsonb field-related queries and figured out that searching over array field documents.data->’metadata’->’areaoflawids’ takes MUCH longer than searching over uuid[] field documents.areasoflawid.

Here are the queries:

```
--search over jsonb array field, takes 6.2 sec, returns 13615 rows
SELECT id FROM documents WHERE data->'metadata'->'areaoflawids' @> '"e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b"'

--search over uuid[] field, takes 600ms, returns 13615 rows
SELECT id FROM documents WHERE areasoflawid @> ARRAY['e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b']::uuid[]
```

Here is the index over jsonb field:

```
CREATE INDEX test_documents_aols_gin_idx
  ON public.documents
  USING gin
  (((data -> 'metadata'::text) -> 'areaoflawids'::text) jsonb_path_ops);
```

And here is the execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT id FROM documents WHERE data->'metadata'->'areaoflawids' @> '"e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b"'


"Bitmap Heap Scan on documents  (cost=6.31..390.78 rows=201 width=4) (actual time=2.297..5859.886 rows=13614 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (((data -> 'metadata'::text) -> 'areaoflawids'::text) @> '"e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b"'::jsonb)"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=4859"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_documents_aols_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..6.30 rows=201 width=0) (actual time=1.608..1.608 rows=13614 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (((data -> 'metadata'::text) -> 'areaoflawids'::text) @> '"e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b"'::jsonb)"
"Planning time: 0.133 ms"
"Execution time: 5862.807 ms"
```

Other queries over jsonb field work with acceptable speed, but this particular search is about 10 times slower than search over separated field. We were expecting it to be a bit slower but not that bad. We consider option of leaving this “areasoflawid” field as a separated field but we would definitely prefer to move it inside the json. I’ve been playing with different indexes and operations (also used ? and ?|) but the search is still slow. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `WHERE data->'metadata'->'areaoflawids' ? 'e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b'`

Comment: Hi, yes, and it didn’t help me much... To use this operation I had to change the index:
```
CREATE INDEX test_documents_aols_gin_idx
  ON public.documents
  USING gin
  (((data -> 'metadata'::text) -> 'areaoflawids'::text));
```

So the query performs the same - 6.0sec
```
SELECT id FROM documents WHERE data->'metadata'->'areaoflawids' ? 'e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b';
```

The execution plan looks the same:

Comment: Can you show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for this query, and also for the other query you are comparing it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your response! We came up with another solution taken from this post: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAONrwUFOtnR909gs+7UOdQQB12+pXsGUYu5YHPtbQk5vaE9Gaw@mail.gmail.com . The query now takes about 600-800ms to execute.
So, here is the solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aol_uuids(data jsonb) RETURNS TEXT[] AS
$$
    SELECT 
        array_agg(value::TEXT) as val
    FROM 
        jsonb_array_elements(case jsonb_typeof(data) when 'array' then data else '[]' end)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;


SELECT id FROM documents WHERE aol_uuids(data->'metadata'->'areaoflawids')@>ARRAY['"e34e0ee5-78e0-4d92-9186-ac69c109408b"']
```

Comment: So you are converting your data model that uses a native array of UUIDs into a JSONB value (increasing the size by more than 2), just to convert it back into a native array of UUIDs when you need to search for it. Sounds weird to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, yes, but these changes are dictated by the requirements. We are creating new level of abstraction in our project so all the entity-specific fields are moving inside the jsonb field. Also, it worth paying attention to the fact that we store not many items inside this array per each record and also we are not tightly restricted by the size of the DB. So the change looks reasonable for us.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the 13,614 candidate matches in the index is very fast (1.608 milliseconds).  The slow part is reading all of those rows from the table itself.  If you turn on track_io_timing, then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, I'm sure you will find you are waiting on IO.  If you run the query several times in a row, does it get faster?

I think you are doing an unequal benchmark here, where one table is already in cache and the alternative table is not.  But it could also be that the new table is too large to actually fit in cache.